# Excel VBA - How to copy row by row from a sheet of workbook to another Workbook's sheet using different subroutine

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to copy data from a sheet of workbook to another workbook, but code showing error 1004. Here is the code in which i encountered error in For loop of Subroutine findDuplicates()

```
Option Explicit

Sub GenerateErrorSheet()
   Dim MyBook As Workbook
   Dim newBook As Workbook
   Dim FileNm As String
   Dim rowCount As Integer

   Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook
   rowCount = 1

   FileNm = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ErrorSheet-" & Date & ".xls"
   Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

   With newBook

      Call findDuplicates(Worksheets("pid"), "PID Generator", rowCount,newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1"))
      rowCount = rowCount + 4
      'Call findDuplicates(Worksheets("behavioural"), "Behavioural Measurement")
      'rowCount = rowCount + 4
      'Call findDuplicates(Worksheets("physical"), "Physical Measurement")
      'rowCount = rowCount + 4
      'Call findDuplicates(Worksheets("biochemical"), "Biochemical Measurement")
      'Save new wb with XLS extension
      .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False

      .Close Savechanges:=False
   End With
   MsgBox "Error Sheet Generated Successfully." & vbNewLine & "Name Of Sheet - ErrorSheet-" & Date & ".xls" & vbNewLine & "Saved Location - " & FileNm
End Sub
```

My findDuplicates subroutine which gives error inside the for loop

```
Sub findDuplicates(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, name As String, ByRef row As Integer, ByVal Sheet2 As Worksheet)
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim numRow As Integer
   numRow = sheet.Range("J2", sheet.Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

   With Sheet2
       Range(Cells(row, "A"), Cells(row, "L")).MergeCells = True
       With Cells(row, "A")
           .Font.name = "Bell MT"
           .Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"
           .Font.Size = 20
           .Font.Color = RGB(255, 99, 71)
           .Value = "Multiple Forms Found in " & name & " for single household"
       End With
       row = row + 1
   End With
   For i = 1 To numRow
        sheet.Rows("i").Copy Sheet2.Rows("row")
        row = row + 1
   Next i
End Sub
```

The Error Showing is -[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wolQl.png)

Locals values just before error - [Locals Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGHh.png)

Comment: *'I want another subroutine because ...'* is not a valid question.

Comment: 'which gives error inside the for loop'
And what error does it give?

Comment: Declare all the objects.

Comment: Its Showing Run time Error - '1004'
Application Defined or Object Defined Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's the Sheet2.Rows("row"). Shouldn't this be just Sheet2.Rows(row) instead?

Edit: Also Sheet.Rows("i") would be sheet.rows(i) probably.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.
Its Working Now